# Don't display questions that contain an ignored tag when the option `Hide questions in your ignored tags` is enabled

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

Ignored questions that contain an ignored tag are briefly shown before being hidden.

Feature request: don't display questions that contain an ignored tag when the option `Hide questions in your ignored tags` is enabled.

Example with the ignored [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), with the option `Hide questions in your ignored tags`:

[image]

Comment: Or, in other words, those questions should be omitted server-side before being sent to you instead of being removed client-side.

Comment: I'd rather the content not be *omitted* server-side but still sent. Just not shown.